# Finding which java programe was killed by Linux OOM killer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, redhat

I deploy six java program in linux server,some was killed.  I know that I can use the command `grep "Killed process" /var/log/messages` to find which process killed by the linux-kernel.But how can I find that the pid belong to my java program.It may be belong to other java program in the same server.The result is:

```
Aug 21 17:05:22 TEST_SERVER kernel: Killed process 2403, UID 700, (java)   total-vm:19970440kB, anon-rss:7472436kB, file-rss:356kB
Aug 21 17:05:22 TEST_SERVER kernel: Killed process 2405, UID 700, (java)    total-vm:19970440kB, anon-rss:7472456kB, file-rss:212kB
Aug 21 17:05:22 TEST_SERVER kernel: Killed process 2511, UID 800, (oracle) total-vm:26509852kB, anon-rss:48836kB, file-rss:4992488kB
```

I know that use  cd /proc/{pid} can find the pid detail,but now my process was killed, and I use the command it says can not find the file or catalog.
I also look at the messages,but still nothing to do.

```
 Out of memory: Kill process 2403 (java) score 114 or sacrifice child
 Aug 21 17:05:22 TEST_SERVER kernel: Killed process 2403, UID 700, (java)     total-vm:19970440kB, anon-rss:7472436kB, file-rss:356kB
 Aug 21 17:05:22 TEST_SERVER kernel: java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da,  order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
 Aug 21 17:05:22 TEST_SERVER kernel: java cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
 Aug 21 17:05:22 TEST_SERVER kernel: Pid: 22393, comm: java Not tainted 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1
```

Answer (score -1):

When OOM-killer is triggered, a bunch of lines are written in /var/log/messages. Instead of using grep, you should look around the lines that contains "Killed process" with less or vim.
You will find a line like "XXXX invoked oom-killer:".

Comment: I have look the messages,but still have nothing to do.I write it in the question.

Comment: You can try to find a pid file with find /var/run -name "*pid" -exec egrep PID {} \;